# How to do custom validation on entity for multitenant setup using Spring + Hibernate

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, multi-tenant, bean-validation

I am trying to validate a field of an Entity using custom ConstraintValidator implementation in a multi-tenancy setup using spring hibernate.
How do we make the custom validator tenant aware? The entity manager and other autowired beans in the validator are always null.

Entity Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "autoupdate_json")
public class AutoupdateJson {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

@Column(name="autoupdate_id")
private String autoupdateId; 

@Column(name="deployment_json", length=10000)
@ValidateAutodeploymentConfig
@Convert(converter=JpaConverterJson.class)
private ApplyInputJson deploymentJson; 
}
```

`
Validation Annotation:

```
@Documented
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = {AutodeploymentConfigValidator.class})
public @interface ValidateAutodeploymentConfig {

String message() default "One or More of the Devices already have perpetual mode settings enabled. Please cancel the existing "
        + " deployment config to add a new one, Updates are not supported. ";

Class<?>[] groups() default {};

Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Validator Implementation:

```
public class AutodeploymentConfigValidator
    implements ConstraintValidator<ValidateAutodeploymentConfig, ApplyInputJson> {

@PersistenceContext
EntityManager entityManager; 

@Autowired
DeviceRepository deviceRepository; 

@Override
public boolean isValid(ApplyInputJson value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    List<String> deviceSerialNumbers = Arrays.asList(value.getDevices().getSerial());
    
    System.out.println("entityManager: " + entityManager);
    System.out.println("repo bean: " + deviceRepository);
}
```

Both the sysouts are null.

Answer (score 0):

The entity manager and device repository are null because `AutodeploymentConfigValidator` is not coming from spring context.
It is created by default constraint validation factory used by hibernate which using no arg constructor.

Try to add `HibernatePropertiesCustomizer` to tell hibernate which validation factory to use. Something like:

```
@Component
public class HibernateCustomizer implements HibernatePropertiesCustomizer {

    private final ValidatorFactory validatorFactory;

    public HibernateCustomizer(ValidatorFactory validatorFactory) {
        this.validatorFactory = validatorFactory;
    }

    public void customize(Map<String, Object> hibernateProperties) {
        hibernateProperties.put("javax.persistence.validation.factory", validatorFactory);
    }
}
```

With this you should be able to use entity manager in your constraint validator.